# Validating dynamically reapetedly added fields in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I know that a fields needs a `name` and `id` to be able to be validated.

My issue is that I need to allow repeatedly added fields to be added to the form, which will have the same `name` (so that I can read them server-side).

As a result, only the first dynamically-added field is validated, others are not, and will get submitted even if empty.

Here is a sample of my basic setup: http://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/07m6bru2/

Is there some kind of work-around for this?

Comment: Correction:  the field only needs a `name`... not an `id` to be validated.   And its `name` **must** be unique... there is no workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

This might not a clean solution but a possible workaround, keep input fields count in a variable and each time create a new control id/name like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var controlNumber = 4; //assume you have 3 controls in form
$('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin      
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
        return false; // for demo
    }
});

$('button').one('click', function () {
    var ctl = '<input name="product['+controlNumber+'][name]" id="form_product[3][name]" data-rule-required="true">';        
    $('#myform').append(ctl);
    controlNumber++;
});
});
```